# error when trying to filter an array to get a subset in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to filter objects array based on the value of one of the parameters in the array. However when i try to do the same, an error is thrown "Argument '[value] is not a function, got undefined.

$scope.model.selection will contain array values based on user selections(say checkboxes)

`$scope.model.selection = ["m1", "m2"`]

I have written the code to get only the _source values from the json as objects. Now i want only the objects which passes a particular condition viz machinename in ["m1"]

My code:

```
var filter;
        filter = sourcearray.filter(function (filterinstance)
                                                  {
                  return filterinstance.machinename in $scope.model.selection;

                                                  });
```

My data:

```
{

        "kal": [
            {
                "_index": "log2015.18",
                "_type": "MT_DETAIL",
                "_sc": null,
                "_source": {
                    "value1": 0,
                    "value2": "2",
                    "value3": "MON",
                    "machine": "m1"
                },
                "sort": [
                    1
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "logw-2015.18",
                "_type": "MT_DETAIL",
                "_sc": null,
                "_source": {
                    "value1": 1,
                    "value2": "3",
                    "value3": "MON1",
                    "machine": "m1"
                },
                "sort": [
                    2
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "log-2015.18",
                "_type": "MT_DETAIL",
                "_sc": null,
                "_source": {
                   "value1": 3,
                    "value2": "265",
                    "value3": "MON2",
                    "machine": "m2"
                },
                "sort": [
                    3
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "log2015.18",
                "_type": "MT_DETAIL",
                "_sc": null,
                "_source": {
                   "value1": 4,
                    "value2": "5",
                    "value3": "MON5",
                    "machine": "m2"
                },
                "sort": [
                    1
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "log2015.18",
                "_type": "MT_DETAIL",
                "_sc": null,
                "_source": {
                    "value1": 7,
                    "value2": "3",
                    "value3": "MON8"
                },
                "sort": [
                    1
                ]
            }
        ]

}
```

Comment: $scope.model.selection is already an array , no need to put it in array again.

Comment: thanks kanhai shah. However i have one small query. when i rewrite the code  var filterinstance = sourcearray.filter(function (el) {
                $log.info(el.machinename);
                return el.machinename in [$scope.model.selection]
            }); it is returning null.